# Unable to create new branch in P4 using integrate

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I've a branch in P4 at

```
//depot/MyDemoInfo/trunk/Server/My_Service
```

& under My_Service, my entire source code is present.

Now, When I'm trying to create a new branch from the above trunk branch, it is giving me error:

I'm trying to create a new release branch as shown below:

```
//depot/MyDemoInfo/1.0/Server/My_Service
```

So, I issued below command after adding it in my client specs:

```
p4 integrate //depot/MyDemoInfo/trunk/Server/My_Service/... //depot/MyDemoInfo/1.0/Server/My_Service/...
```

It gives below errors:

```
//depot/MyDemoInfo/1.0/Server/My_Service//abc.txt - can't integrate from //depot/MyDemoInfo/trunk/Server/My_Service/abc.txt#1 (moved from //depot/MyDemoInfo/trunk/Server/My_Service/abc.txt; provide a branch view that maps this file, or use -Di to disregard move/deletes)
```

For all files in my trunk branch, it is giving same above error. Can some one help me what is wrong going on here??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a `p4 integrate`, the destination for the integration should be mapped in your `perforce client workspace` which is what this error indicates:

`provide a branch view that maps this file, or use -Di to disregard move/deletes`

Using `p4 client` or `p4v`, map the following perforce depot `//depot/MyDemoInfo/1.0/Server/My_Service` into your client workspace to some directory on your machine say: `/myp4workspace/MyDemoInfo/1.0/Server/My_Service`

Then do this:

```
cd /myp4workspace/MyDemoInfo/1.0/Server/My_Service
p4 integrate //depot/MyDemoInfo/trunk/Server/My_Service/... ...

# This is optional, but a regular workflow to make sure you resolve all the conflicts
# Display any conflicts (there shouldn't be any since this is the first time you're integrating into this location)
p4 resolve -n ... 

# If there are any, use p4 resolve -as ... , p4 resolve -am ... , and then p4 resolve ...

# Submit your changes after verifying it is correct
p4 submit ...
```

And one more thing you might want to take care of is, run `p4 integrate` with the `-t -d` option so that it preserves file-types, and brings in any deleted file changes (although these 2 options might not be really required in your case but nothing wrong in specifying them).

Also you can run `p4 where` to confirm that you're in the right perforce depot location before doing any integrations.

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing slash in your `integrate` command. The target/destination should include a slash before the `...`.

Try this:

```
p4 integrate //depot/MyDemoInfo/trunk/Server/My_Service/... //depot/MyDemoInfo/1.0/Server/My_Service/...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

That may fix it. If not, confirm that the destination is in your client spec mapping.

Comment: Sorry, it was a type. The / is present & I'm still getting error