# Integrate streams from different depots. Some files not integrate

Tags: perforce

I have following structure:

`DepotA` have streams `main` (mainline stream) and `dev` (development stream) as mains' child.
`DepotB` have streams `main` (mainline stream) and `dev` (development stream) as mains' child.

I populated `//DepotA/dev`. `//DepotB/dev` is empty. Now I'm trying to merge `//DepotA/dev/...` to `//DepotB/dev/...`. I can't do this with p4v - I simply have weird error. But I can do it with command line. But after merge the streams are different - I checked the sizes of the folders on my machine - `//DepotA/dev` is 43Gb but `//DepotB/dev` is 18Gb. Where're other files? Why they didn't merged?

Comment: Is this just an experiment? If //DepotA/main and //DepotB/main are completely unrelated mainlines, why are you trying to merge their development streams together?

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton Actually it's not an experiment. We have a complicated structure with a third party libraries and so on (hard to explain). And the perforce have a possibility to merge from unrelated depots (at least documentation says that). But it doesn't work.

Comment: You always need to run "p4 resolve" after "p4 merge" -- did you do that yet?  Did you try doing the merge again to see whether there are any files that are being skipped because of some error condition?    Are all of the files writable in the target stream (i.e. in a "share" path)?  What was the "weird error" you got in P4V?

Comment: @Sam Stafford I have nothing to resolve. The target folder is empty. The error tells me "//depot/someFile - can't integrate from //depot/someFile#1 (moved from //depot/someFile; provide a branch view that maps this file, or use -Di to disregard move/deletes). But I have view, half of the files are merged somehow.

Comment: This is making more sense now.  Give this a try: p4 integrate -Di //DepotA/dev/... //DepotB/dev/...

Comment: Tried, didn't help. Found this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346983/unable-to-create-new-branch-in-p4-using-integrate and it helped me, thought I couldn't find documentation for -d option.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect some of the size difference is due to the fact that files have not yet been changed in '//DepotB/dev', so lazy copies have been created.

These are simply pointers to the original files. Physical files are created once the source or targets are changed.

It can be tricky to investigate integration issues without taking a detailed look at the history, so I recommend you contact Perforce Support, if you have further questions:

http://www.perforce.com/support-services